# Angular material datepicker - add content (close button)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

i am trying to add a button to my angular material datepicker. 
The button should be added in the top right corner and should close the datepicker on click.

Also i am trying to add additional content inside my datepicker. Since i have disabled dates inside my datepicker i want to add some kind of legend which says that gray dates don't hold any data and therefore can't be selected.

Is there any possibility in adding additional divs or buttons?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to design your own datepicker with Angular Material Component Development Kit (CDK).