# Angular6 Material Datepicker add content to the template

Tags: angular, datepicker, calendar, angular-material

I would like to know how to achieve it.
I have found

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822543/how-to-override-template-for-angular-material-2-datepicker/50250591#50250591) I found how it should be done, by modifying the component, not extending it but I really can't find how to do it in the code. More information would be great. How can I extend or modify the template of mat-calendar? Inside the mat-calendar code I can't find the template.

And in this second case I found how to add a button [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555578/angular-material-datepicker-add-content-close-button) but I have the same problem, do'nt know how to do it, could someone provide any exaple where I can see how to achieve it.

Answer (score 5):

This is an ugly way of doing it, but it shows how to complete the task via manipulating the document object.

- I attempted via @ViewChild and trying the getConnectedOverlayOrigin method but I could not figure it out.
- This was the only way I was able to manipulate the calender content in the DOM.
- Hopefully someone will post a native Angular/Material way of doing this, I would like to know how personally.

**Using the Opened event:**

```
<mat-datepicker (opened)="opened()" #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

**Component Method:**

```
 opened() {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.onclick = function () {
      alert("blabla");
    };
    var t = document.createTextNode("Click Me");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(btn);

    setTimeout(() => {
      var element = document.getElementsByTagName('mat-datepicker-content');
      element[0].appendChild(btn);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Marshal, I'm going to try it in your way, if it fits with my needs. Would be great to know a more native way